# Add apollo client dev tools to chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, apollo, apollo-client

I have downloaded the chrome extension Apollo Client Devtools. However it is not visible when devtools are open. Is there a way of adding this or is it a bug? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, tried closing the tab and re-opening, closing chrome and re-opening but nothing of that helped. Then I installed a totally different extension (React Developer Tools) and all of a sudden the Apollo dev tools showed up, it seems that adding a new plugin somehow refreshed the plugins and it showed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close and re-open the tab.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup on the Apollo Client the following field:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  connectToDevTools: true,
  ....
})
```